# Getting `conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible` error

Tags: swift, swift5

So im trying to sort out an issue here. I have this data model object, and I am getting back from an endpoint, an array of [ContentItem.ContentID] types, in another class to what im showing in the bottom. I want to convert that array to an array of [String], but i am getting the following error:
`Cannot convert value of type '[ContentItem.ContentID]' to expected argument type '[String]'`

When I try to FlatMap it to a String, I get:
`Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that '[ContentItem.ContentID]' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'`

I get an error saying I need the following data model to conform to  `LosslessStringConvertible` but im not sure how.

```swift
import Foundation

struct ContentItem: Codable, Equatable {
    enum ContentID: Codable {
        case text(String)
        case number(Int)

        case empty
    }
    enum SeriesID: Codable {
        case text(String)
        case number(Int)

        case empty
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case contentID = "content_id"
        case seriesID = "series_id"
        case rank = "rank"
        case score = "score"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        rank = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .rank)
        score = try values.decode(Float.self, forKey: .score)
        seriesID = try values.decode(SeriesID.self, forKey: .seriesID)
        contentID = try values.decode(ContentID.self, forKey: .contentID)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(score, forKey: .score)
        try container.encode(rank, forKey: .rank)
        try container.encode(seriesID, forKey: .seriesID)
        try container.encode(contentID, forKey: .contentID)
    }

    let rank: Int
    let score: Float
    let seriesID: SeriesID
    let contentID: ContentID

}

extension ContentItem.SeriesID: Equatable, Hashable {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .text(let text):
            try container.encode(text)
        case .number(let number):
            try container.encode(number)
        case .empty:
            break
        }
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.hashValue)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let text = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .text(text)
        } else if let number = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .number(number)
        } else {
            //assertionFailure("Unknown id type")
            self = .empty
        }
    }

}

extension ContentItem.ContentID: Equatable, Hashable {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .text(let text):
            try container.encode(text)
        case .number(let number):
            try container.encode(number)
        case .empty:
            break
        }
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.hashValue)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let text = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .text(text)
        } else if let number = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .number(number)
        } else {
//            assertionFailure("Unknown id type")
            self = .empty
        }
    }

}
```

The class calling it, containing the error is:

```
...
func GET(endpoint: Endpoint, params: [String: String]?) -> AnyPublisher<[ContentItem.ContentID], APIError> {

        guard let token = self.apiKey else {
            fatalError("Missing Credentials. Please add a valid Samba token")
        }

        var request = generaterURLRequest(endpoint: endpoint, params: params)
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .receive(on: apiQueue)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: PaginatedResponse<ContentItem>.self, decoder: JSONDecoder() )
            .mapError { error -> APIError in
                switch error {
                    case is URLError:
                        return APIError.urlError(error as! URLError)
                    case is DecodingError:
                        return APIError.decodingError(error as! DecodingError)
                    default:
                        return APIError.genericError(error as! DecodingError)
                    }
            }
            .map {$0.results.map { String($0.contentID)}}
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code _to convert that array to an array of [String]_? Where is the code _to FlatMap it to a String_? Please show them.

Comment: OK ive added it. Sorry about that. The error is in `.map {$0.results.map { String($0.contentID)}}`

Comment: Makes no sense. ContentID is an enum. It cannot be cast to a String. What String would you expect to get?

Comment: @matt The reason I have it defined that way in an enumeration is that the result from an endpoint called for content ID could either be a string or int. Maybe there is a better way of doing that but either way, in the failing function I want to pass an array of content IDs to another function as a string.

Comment: Happy to have suggestions on how to improve the other scenario as well.

Comment: You declare the return type of `GET(endpoint:parameter:)` as `AnyPublisher<[ContentItem.ContentID], APIError>`, but you are trying to make `AnyPublisher<[String], APIError>` with the line `.map {$0.results.map { String($0.contentID)}}`. Which type do you want to return from `GET`?

Comment: So I tried doing it in a different function as well so I don’t think  the issue is the return type. Grant it it won’t work anyway on that but trying elsewhere I try to convert publisher GET returns to that and still fail. I think issue lies in the enum

Comment: I have no difficulty recognizing the pattern of the String / Int enum as expressing a union type. That's neither here nor there. I am simply asking you to specify, as you must to satisfy the compiler, what you think casting such an enum to a String would mean. What should happen when it is a String? (I think we know that.) What should happen when it is an Int? (I think I can guess.) What should happen when it is an `.empty`? If you specify that, you will know how to write an enum-to-string conversion method. But without such a method, your code is illegal and incomprehensible.

Comment: ***I don’t think the issue is the return type.*** The return type is not the only thing causing the issue, but unless knowing the right return type, I cannot write an answer appropriate for your code. Before writing _I don’t think_, you should better reply to my question directly, which type do you want to return from GET?

Comment: OK maybe two conflated issues. So answering your question regarding what to get from GET. I want `ContentItem.ContentID` to be a string. Therefore, the enum should be constructed that way. If it is an int, it should be casted to string. Let's start with that...

Comment: And perhaps there is a better way of handling dynamic encoding and decoding of a type (as it could be a string or int). If you have thoughts around that let me know.. Thanks OOper

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just say `String($0.contentID)`, where `$0.contentID` is a ContentID enum. There is no built-in magical way to convert a ContentID enum to a String. The compiler cannot guess what you want such an expression to mean. You have to tell it! For example, you might say:

```
extension String {
    init(_ cid:ContentID) {
        switch cid {
            case .empty:
                self = ""
            case .text(let s):
                self = s
            case .number(let i):
                self = String(i)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a best practice way of doing it? It looks like it would work but im wondering if there is a better way of decoding a dynamic type and casting to a string...

Comment: I don't understand the question. I don't know what a "dynamic type" is or what "decoding a dynamic type" means. You complained that the phrase `String($0.contentID)` was causing a compiler error. I told you why and even suggested something you might do about it.